# Bash substitution cut off end of string

Tags: bash, shell, substitution

I have bash script which should replace some placeholders in text template by users input.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run this script as bash command like: bash create-apache-site.sh

read -p 'Write url without www and http prefixes: ' url

template=$(</etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf)
template2=("${template/1*****/$url}")

echo "$template2" > /home/Camo/template.txt
```

Template file is multi-line string with placeholders (1*****, 2*****, ...) which looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin xxxx.xxxxx@gmail.com
        ServerName 1*****

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www/2*****/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www/3*****/access.log combined

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/4*****
        <Directory /var/www/html/5*****/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} = 6*****
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

But the result of this script is this damaged file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin xxxx.xxxxx@gmail.com
        ServerName ooooooooooooooo.com
```

As you can see substitution cut off the end of the string. Can somebody tell me please what is wrong with it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: nothing is wrong, it works exactly as it should.. You are better off using `sed` to replace a separate template file, or use `bash here document` to replace portions of your inline template with variables values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape your `*` for the replace to work.
Maybe a better way is to not use `*` as your placeholder? But I leave that up to you.

Try this:

*(I also made the replacement global so that you can reuse the same placeholder several times within the file)*

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Run this script as bash command like: bash create-apache-site.sh

read -p 'Write url without www and http prefixes: ' url

template=$(</etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf)
template2=("${template//1\*\*\*\*\*/$url}")

echo "$template2" > /home/Camo/template.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the problem. I replaced it as __placeholder__